# Checkout results in code 100

Tags: tfs, build

I'm trying to create new build definitions for our new environments.  I copied existing build definitions, changing the names as appropriate.  Unfortunately, when I reach the following statement:

```
<Exec
  WorkingDirectory="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)"
  Command="$(TeamFoundationVersionControlTool) checkout AssemblyVersionInfo.txt AssemblyVersionInfo.cs"/>
```

I get the following error:

> C:(...)\IncrementAssemblyVersion.proj (16): The command ""C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\tf.exe"
>   checkout AssemblyVersionInfo.txt AssemblyVersionInfo.cs" exited with
>   code 100.

I have confirmed that the files are indeed at $(BuildProjectFolderPath).  Why might I be getting code 100 for the new environments but not for existing environments?

Comment: A bit more information.  On the Visual Studio Command Prompt, I moved to where the files are located, made sure the files exist, and then typed 'tf checkout AssemblyVersionInfo.txt' and got the error



The item AssemblyVersionInfo.txt could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: Why are you using different build definitions for environments? Why not build a release pipeline in a release management tool?

Comment: Mostly because we are handling our different environments for different reasons.  We are using the same build process template for all the environments, but the environments have different sources to build from.